# After suspend, on resume, Ubuntu briefly shows content of session before displaying the lock screen

Tags: suspend, lock-screen, gdm, privacy

This happens to me about 10% of the times when I resume my laptop from suspend mode. I feel that this is problematic for privacy because someone physically near my laptop could briefly see what is in the session without knowing the password.

I'm available to give you more info if needed. I haven't found info on this bug, though.

My config:

Ubuntu 21.04 (installed fresh three months ago, but I don't think it is specific to this release), using GNOME, on Xorg, on a ThinkPad X1 8th gen (released mid-2020).
I use to slow down my CPU to max 1.6 GHz most of the time when I am on battery, but this should be irrelevant.

This bug persists through two installs.

Comment: Bug reports are off topic. Please do not report bugs here since they are not triaged on Ask Ubuntu.  If you want to help this get fixed, please [file a proper bug report](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: This is the same bug as: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1532508

Answer (score 4):

This is a highly visible bug to the developers. If you do determine more information relevant to repeating this bug, please share.

Same as: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1532508

Very Similar: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-settings-daemon/+bug/1335835

Very Similar: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1520882

Similar: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/960073

See also: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/3294

Comment: Thanks! So basically we are screwed: this bug has been around for years and has not been fixed.... So it probably won't anytime soon either.... But if the issue is reproducing this bug, I may help, but I don't know how – perhaps by sending logs? Which ones, though? I am not familiar with launchpad and bug reports, but the first link you mention seems to still be 'active' anyway.

Comment: @JohannesLemonde Subscribing to the bug also helps, as it increases its heat. The more heat the more serious the bug and it's most probable to draw the developer's attention in order to fix it.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog Thank you for mentioning that! So I just announced myself as affected (+4 heat points).